# How to generate a custom sequential number with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Is there any way to generate a custom sequential number like the following? 
I want the Number to be incremented with grouping by the Code and Year.

```
Code    Year    Number
A       2016    1
A       2016    2
A       2016    3
B       2016    1
B       2016    2
C       2016    1
A       2017    1
A       2017    2
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Sorry, I was too ambiguous what I want. I want to generate the unique number when I query, so if I ask a new number in the above data context with Code:A and Year:2017, I want the Number to be 3. I guess to get the Number properly in a future I need to save the Code and Year with the Number.

Comment: Do you want to have this number in the table, or when you query the data?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that the generated number must be unique, so I guess the numbers have to be saved in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to assign `Number` per `Code`,`Year` grouping.

```
SELECT *,
    Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code, [Year] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM tbl
```

Replace `SELECT NULL` with the column you want the order to be based from.

Comment: Oh such a quick reply. Thanks a lot! I guess all I need to do is save that number for a future inquiry.